# how to develop lexer and parser in java?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

Hi im a student and new to compiler design concepts.I dont know how to develop a lexer and parser in java?  Please help me to do this giv me a guide lines...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) to defined the grammar and it can generate the compilers and you can also construct interpreters.

Comment: No, ANTLR does not generate interpreters.

Comment: @Bart Kiers - corrected my post

Comment: Thanks. But your answer is still below par, IMHO. Although ANTLR (and tools like it) are sometimes called "[compiler compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler)s", saying that ANTLR generates a compiler, is (again IMHO) misleading. ANTLR generates, given a grammar, a lexer and/or parser. And your remark that "you can also construct interpreters", is self-evident: of course someone can create an interpreter... Sorry to bust your balls, but the answer isn't worth much, as is.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know about [JavaCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaCC)?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn to write a compiler, you should also study the fundamentals of how compilers work. MIT OpenCourseWare[1](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-035-computer-language-engineering-spring-2010/index.htm) has a good class on the subject, with links to good textbooks.

For links to actual lexer / parser tools, you can look at the other answers, or use Google. I think the course may also mention which tools it used.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the Interpreter Pattern on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern), it also provides a parser for completeness.